# Corollary 7, Section 3.5 of Hungerford’s Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and consider the polynomial $$f=x^2y+x^3y+x^4+xy+y^2+r \in R[x,y].$$ Observe that $f=y^2 + (x^2+ x^3 + x)y + (x^4 + r)$, whence $f\in R[x][y]$. Similarly, $f=x^4+yx^3+yx^2+yx+(y^2+r)\in R[y][x]$. This suggest that $R[x,y]$ is isomorphic to both $R[x][y]$ and $R[y][x]$. More generally we have:
>
> **Corollary 5.7.** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $n$ a positive integer. For each $k$ ($1\leq k \lt n$) there are isomorphisms of rings $R[x_1,…,x_k][x_{k+1},…,x_n] \cong R[x_1,…,x_n]\cong R[x_{k+1},…,x_n][x_1,…,x_k]$.
>
> **Proof.** The corollary may be proved by directly constructing the isomorphisms or by using the universal mapping property of Theorem 5.5 as follows …………

**Question:** I don’t understand why $R[x_1,…,x_n]$ is isomorphic to $R[x_1,…,x_k][x_{k+1},…,x_n]$ and $R[x_{k+1},…,x_n] [x_1,…,x_k]$, instead of equality. Motivation for corollary (first paragraph) even shows that $R[x,y]=R[y][x]=R[x][y]$. Some author define ring of polynomial in $n$ indeterminant as follows: $R[x_1,…,x_n]:=R[x_1,…,x_{n-1}][x_n]$. Hungerford defined polynomial in $n$ indeterminant as follows: Let $R$ be a ring with identity and denote by $R[x_1,…,x_n]$ the set of all functions $f: N^n \to R$ such that $f(u)\neq 0$ for at most a finite number of elements $u$ of $N^n$. I think, corollary 5.7 trying to show both definition of polynomial in $n$ indeterminant are equivalent.

To be honest, I don’t completely understand author proof of corollary using theorem 5.5 ([universal mapping property](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/481851/861687)). I didn’t write that part of the proof because in my opinion it is messy and deviate from the actual question. I was trying to prove corollary by directly constructing isomorphism, I proved following: Let $f\in R[x_1][x_2,…,x_n]$. Then
$$ \begin{align}
f &= \sum_{i=0}^ma_i x_2^{k_{i2}}\cdots x_n^{k_{in}} \\ &= \sum_{i=0}^m \left( \sum_{j=0}^{n} b_{ij} x_1^{k_{ij1}} \right) x_2^{k_{i2}}\cdots x_n^{k_{in}} \\ &= \sum_{i=0}^m \sum_{j=0}^{n} b_{ij} x_1^{k_{ij1}} x_2^{k_{i2}}\cdots x_n^{k_{in}} \\ &= \sum_{i\times j\in [m]\times [n]} b_{ij} x_1^{k_{ij1}} x_2^{k_{i2}}\cdots x_n^{k_{in}}
\end{align}$$
where $[m]=\{0,1,…,m\}$ and $[n]=\{0,1,…,n\}$. So $f\in R[x_1,…,x_n]$ and $R[x_1][x_2,…,x_n]\subseteq R[x_1,…,x_n]$. Clearly $R[x_1][x_2,…,x_n]\supseteq R[x_1,…,x_n]$. Thus $R[x_1][x_2,…,x_n] = R[x_1,…,x_n]$. Similarly argument (with slight changes in notation) show that $R[x_1,…,x_k][x_{k+1},…,x_n]=R[x_1,…,x_n]=R [x_{k+1},…,x_n][x_1,…,x_k]$. My proof must be fundamentally wrong but I don’t know where exactly.

Comment: Take $n=2$ and write down the two rings. They are not equal but isomorphic. The first ring $R[y][x]$ has only one variable $x$ and coefficients $R[y]$, the second ring $R[x,y]$ has two variables $x,y$. So they cannot be equal.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Author showed in first paragraph, $R[x,y]\subseteq R[x][y]$. Inclusion in another direction $\supseteq$ holds clearly. So $R[x,y] = R[x][y]$.

Comment: I don't have Hungerford in front of me, but neither inclusion is an actual set inclusion. $R[x][y]$ consists of elements of the form $(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n,\ldots)$ where $a_i\in R[x]$ and $a_i=0$ for almost all $i$ (so each $a_i$ is a sequence $a_i=(b_{i0},b_{i1},\ldots)$ with $b_{ij}\in R$ $0$ for almost all $j$); whereas $R[x.,y]$ consists of functions $f\colon\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to R$ that are $0$ almost everywhere. The two are different sets. There are *natural inclusions* one can describe going each way that are inverses of each other, but they are not literal subset inclusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $R[x]$ is defined to be the set of almost null sequences of elements of $R$; that is, functions $\mathbb{N}\to R$ that are zero at almost all natural numbers; the $x$ represents the sequence $(0,1,0,\ldots,0,\ldots)$, addition is componentwise, etc.

The ring $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is defined to be the set of almost null functions $f\colon\mathbb{N}^n\to R$; we identify $x_1$ with the function that takes the value $1_R$ at $(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ and $0$ elsewhere, etc.

So, for example, $R[x,y]$ is the set of functions $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to R$ that are $0$ at almost all elements of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. By contrast, $R[x][y]$ is the set of almost null sequences of elements of $R[x]$; that is, it is the set of almost null sequences of almost null sequences of elements of $R$. The two are not *equal*, but they are isomorphic. Likewise, $R[y][x]$ is the set of almost null sequences of elements of $R[y]$, so it is not *equal* to $R[x][y]$. Because in $R[x][y]$ the element "$y$" represents the sequence $(0,1_{R[x]},0,0,0,\ldots)$, whereas in $R[y][x]$, $y$ represents the element $(y,0,0,0,\ldots)$.

The computations you make are actually computations of *isomorphisms*, because you are glossing over the difference between, for example, almost null sequences of elements of $R[x]$ with the almost null sequences of elements of $R[y]$. Those differences are elided by the very isomorphisms you are trying to show are not neceessary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think, crux of this post boils down to my [last post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4837130/861687). I would really appreciate if you can see that post and add something you feel like missed in existing answer.